# What is the meaning of the verb "lines" in this context?

Tags: histology

What is the meaning of the verb "lines" in this context?

> "Epithelial tissue covers body surfaces, **lines** body cavities and
>   form glands"

I searched in the dictionary but I found a lot of results and I'm not sure which one is matched.

Comment: (transitive) To cover the inner surface of (something), originally especially with linen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because   it's english language, not specific biology terminology

Comment: You've already had another question closed for this exact reason. Please use one of the English sites you're already a member of to ask basic English grammatical questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lines* in that context is the verb form of the noun *lining* which is a surface that forms an inner boundary of an object. [Here's a dictionary entry.](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=*&Query=lining)